# QueueTrigger templates not showing in Function App?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions, azure-queues

I'm trying to Create a function triggered by Azure Queue storage and following steps from this documentation - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function

However when I try to create Timer function query trigger templates shows as empty to select.

It should be like this - 
[image]

But what I can see - 
[image]

Please let me know any solution for this.

Comment: I can see the templates right now. Try refresh?

Comment: @Mikhail  just now refreshed but still empty

Comment: Which region are you in? We have a few reports of issues creating new apps from templates out of some locations in Asia we are investigating.

Comment: yes, we are experiencing the issue in India region as well. No templates are showing up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue on the Azure Functions side, and it has now been resolved. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Yes I can see the templates now.